# How can I call a "create" action from the link_to helper?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have seen this question answered here, but unfortunately the answer does not work. FYI this is a Rails 2.3.11 application.

I want to call create with this link_to helper against a RESTful resource:

```
link_to("Add", part_types_path(myid), :method => :post)
```

Now very, very strangely, the id that I'm passing in to the URL helper is being interpreted as "format" by the Rails application! So the link comes out to be:

```
/part_types.12345
```

where "12345" is the id. Crazy!

I am missing something very basic for sure, but I have NEVER seen Rails try to call an object id a format.

Here is the routes entry:

```
map.resources :part_types, :collection => { :part_list => :get }
```

and here is the result from "rake routes"

```
POST   /part_types(.:format)    {:controller=>"part_types", :action=>"create"}
```

Notice the absence of any sort of id!

Comment: Please show your config/routes.rb file or type rake routes and show us the output from that. Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The route with the name `part_types` refers to the `index` action if the method is `GET` and to the `create` action if the method is `POST`. Neither of those actions have parameterized paths (in contrast to `show` which should look like `/part_types/:id`). `create` is supposed to create a new record and return its id - you usually don't pass them in the request as unique id generation is easier on the server.

Your first argument will be interpreted as the format because the route does not take any parameters. Compare this to the following:

- `part_type_path(1)` should return `/part_types/1`
- `part_type_path(1, :json)` should return `/part/types/1.json`.

Check [actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb#L1196) to see how `resources` is defined.